# Referencing python variable inside functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code to delete all the copies of a file in a certain directory keeping only one of them.

It works fine if i comment out the first four lines in the `delete()` function but if i don't it gives me a error that local variable list1 referenced before assignment. Also I tried using something called global but it didn't help me much as it gave error saying that it is `NoneType`.
Please help me i am just a intermediate beginner in Python.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
def stripe(lis):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        lis[0] = lis[0].strip()
def scan(pat):
    pat = os.path.abspath(pat)
    files = os.listdir(pat)
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(pat,file)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            list1.append(file)
            list2.append('{0}'.format(filepath))
        elif os.path.isdir(filepath):
            scan(filepath)
def delete():
    list1_1 = stripe(list1)
    list2_1 = stripe(list2)
    list1 = list1_1
    list2 = list2_1
    length = len(list1)
    #length = length - 1
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        item = list1[0]
        a = list1[0]
        b = list2[0]
        del list1[0]
        del list2[0]
        if item in list1:
            try:
                os.remove(list2[list1.index(item)])
                #del list1[list1.index(item)]
                #del list2[list1.index(item)]
            except:
                print('sorry',list1[0],'could not be deleted',sep = ' ')
            print('wow')
        i += 1
        #list1.append(a)
        #list2.append(b)
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You can just consider the first 5 lines of the delete function. Because the error is coming there only

Comment: @ChiefVOLDERMORT Then ideally, you would supply a five line sample that exhibits the same behaviour. Typically you will discover the error as you pair your program back to the essence of the problem. That's part of our craft.

Comment: Sorry I will take care of that from the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` looks like the right option for you, but if you say it gives error, use the way that comes to mind first. list1 and list2 can be the parameters of the `delete()` function.

Something like this:

```
def delete(list1, list2):
    ...

def foo():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    ...
    delete(list1, list2)
```

Also, as I said, `global` is always an option. Here is an easy example:

```
list = []

def foo():
    global list
    list.append(1234)

def foo2():
    global list
    print(list)

foo()
foo2()
```

Output:

```
[1234]
```

Comment: When i used global it just made a new variable list1 of type none and replaced my old one . But the first one is good thanks